# Deployment of managed package

Tags: managed-package, deployment, unit-test

I have a managed package which is going to be installed in several enterprise orgs.

Salesforce while deployment all unit tests will be run and if they all success with 75% code coverage then only you can deploy.

My question is "Do all tests run in dev org only or they also run enterprise org while installing the package?"

Comment: Is that a 3rd party package? or you are writing it?

Comment: I am writing it.

Comment: Are you deploying your managed package, or installing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you ***deploy*** managed package code, your tests will always be executed against the target org you are deploying into.

If you are ***installing*** your managed package into another org, then your tests will only be executed against the target org if you explicitly request them to be run on install using the @isTest(OnInstall=true) annotation.

Comment: What do you mean by "deploying" a managed package? There used to be a deploy button but this did not run tests, it just changed the custom objects from "In Development" to "Deployed". This was removed a few releases ago.

Comment: Since the question's author (@doga) used the phrase "deploy managed package", which is ambiguous, I took the question to be referring to either of 2 things: (1) Deploying code (using Change Sets / IDE / Ant, etc.) that is included in a managed package dev org into another org (perhaps for creating a new package, forking the code, etc.) (2) Installing a managed package version into an org

Comment: @zachelrath so on installing a managed package salesforce doesn't run tests. Does this mean that if I am successfully able to upload a managed package from dev org then this will install in target org for sure without any problem?

Answer (score 0):

75% test coverage is required for all classes included in your managed package application.

When you add components(apex classes, triggers etc) to package, then test coverage for all these classes is calculated and not all of your developer org classes.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

If you ask : will my test run be executed on the dev environment only? the answer is NO, it will also be executed when deploying to the prod env.

When deploying your package to the production env, your test class/functions are executed as well.

Always remember to use [test data correctly](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_deploying.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_deploying.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

Comment: This is wrong. Managed package tests are only executed if they have the @isTest(OnInstall=true) annotation on them. By default no managed packaged apex tests are run on package install.

Instead they are run in the dev org when the package is uploaded.

Comment: when uploaded you mean: deployed?

Comment: There is no concept of deployment in managed package development as far as I'm aware. The button to create a package is labeled "Upload" - and this is when apex tests are run on the packaged code.

Comment: Absolutely correct about having to specify OnInstall=true to execute during package install. But, as I understand it, you still have to have enough of those set to true to reach the 75% code coverage on install.

Comment: @kibitzer I just published a test managed package where every single test fails on install and it installed successfully into a test org. I've been working with them for years and they really don't run tests on install, I promise!

Comment: Agreed with ca_peterson. If @doga is referring to installing a managed package, then the answer to his question is NO, tests will NOT be executed when installing a managed package into an org (unless @isTest(OnInstall=true). But if the author is referring to deploying code (using Change Sets, IDE, Ant) that is included in a managed package dev org into another org (perhaps to branch the code), then the answer is YES, ALL tests in the destination org (including BOTH those in the code being transferred and tests already in the destination org) WILL be run.

Comment: Interesting - so they only require the 75% on the package upload and not on the install. That presents an interesting dilemma to package developers - keep oninstall false and deploy, but have no idea if your application will work correctly, or leave it on and have some confidence that your app will work on the target org....